# Web application account confirmation security flow

Tags: security, security-policy

I have a question about security flow of confirmation link.

I have a website on which you have to fill your email address and password after filing these information my app sends an email with a secure link  to user email address. After clicking on confirmation email user automatically gets logged inside the application.

Now question :

Is there a security risk to auto login user on clicking of confirmation link ?

Comment: “[…] my app sends an *insecure* email with a secure link to user email address.” ;)

Comment: @Gumbo sorry insecure email ?

Comment: It’s very unlikely that every link between your mail server, the recipient’s mail server, and finally the recipient’s client computer is protected and that you can trust the parties that are involved in the delivery. See [privacy concerns of emails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Privacy_concerns) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Is there and security risk to auto login user on clicking of confirmation link? Yes and no. It depends on what is in the link. What I would do is I would have two field in database activate_code, that is randomly generated and is_activated which is defaulted to 0. Then I will send a link to activation code and another email with activation link. Once at activation link, user will fill code and account will be activated. redirect him to login page.
Do not send user emails or any other information. just send random codes or something similar
That is my cent!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a security concern, as [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) [points out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Privacy_concerns).

Since the user has provided an email & password, why not require he be logged in to access his confirmation page?